# Gröbner Basis and linear basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

Let $I$ be an ideal of a polynomial algebra $A$ with a Gröbner basis $G$. Suppose we know how to describe the leading terms of all elements in $G$, denoted by $\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}$, so that we can give an explicit basis for the vector space $A/I$, denoted by $\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$. 
Now, suppose we have a principal ideal $J=\langle g\rangle$. How to construct a Gröbner basis for $I+J$ and an explicit basis for $A/(I+J)$ with the data above?

Comment: If I understand well $I$ is a zero-dimensional ideal (and in this case the leading terms are powers of the variables.)